# Normalize End Date - Nulls or separate table

Tags: null, storage, date

I was hoping for some advice on best practice in schema design - as far as End Date values are concerned.

In this case it is for a Suppliers table - we are required to store information on the Start Date and - should the relationship finish the End Date.

In an environment with low Supplier turnover - I can see the argument for allowing a nullable end date column in the Supplier Table.

Conversely, in a high turnover environment for pushing SuppierID and EndDate into a separate SupplierEndDate table.

The majority of articles I have read - have concluded that it should be judged on a case by case basis. However, I tend to lean more toward creating SupplierEndDate Table.

Is there a definitive best practice for OLTP schema or at least a favoured approach?

Comment: Excellent point - thank you very much for taking the time to consider and respond. Separate table it shall be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the *supplier* 'comes back' then do you want to set the *EndDate* to null again or do you want to keep track of the periods in which the supplier supplied to you? In the last case you must put the *StartDate* and *EndDate* in a separate table. If you put it in a separate table then you always must do a join to see if it is an active *supplier* unless you put an active Y/N switch in the supplier row.

Comment: @Soap said: Excellent point - thank you very much for taking the time to consider and respond. Separate table it shall be!